# Numpy setting j, j+1, j+2 to a

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a short-code efficient way of "glueing" two arrays together such that if the arrays differ in length then the glued product must be such that the values from the longer are filled between values from the smaller untill the the new product has the same length as sum of the length of the two arrays? Or: Is there a way to create an array where x = [a j j j b j j j ], that is to say, take array that has values [a b], create a new one by filling 3 js between each element of that array to get : [a j j j b]

There is the obvious way of doing this by a loop since I know the size of the product beforehand but I suspect there must be a more "numpyic" solution at hand.

It is easy to do when both arrays I want to "glue" are of the same size and the product is [a j b j c j], ie every other as can be seen in this:

```
np.append(np.zeros((10,1)),np.ones((10,1)),1).reshape(2*10)
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
    1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
but you cannot do
np.append(np.zeros((10,1)),np.ones((20,1)),1).reshape(20+10)
```

I apologize if the question isn't clear enough, please do tell which parts I can clarify, my English is broken.

Comment: What would you like the result in the second case (last line of code)  to look like?

Comment: 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 and so on, essentially since ones has twice the length and the total is then of length 3 then to get to that length 3 vector one must cram two values from ones between every value from zeros. I want this to be generalized to cases where ones (or any other vector) is N times larger, then N values must be filled between every value of zeros (or any other vector).

Comment: what happens when one array is size 10 and the other is 15?

Comment: Ah yes I should've mentioned that, I am doing this for this hobby-compression of audio project of mine and I am not allowing sizes that are not multiples of eachother. If one is 10 then the other must be an integer multiple of 10, or 10 must be an integer multiple of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `len(A) == n` and `len(B) == N` and `N`is a multiple of `n`, ie there is some integer `m` such that `N = m*n`, and  you can do:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros(10)
B = np.ones(20)

n = len(A)
C = np.concatenate([A.reshape(n, 1), B.reshape(n, -1)], axis=1)
C = C.ravel()
```

This is pretty much what you have in the question, but the trick is to reshape B to be (n, m) instead of (N, 1) ie (10, 2) instead of (20, 1) in this case. The `-1` in `reshape` is short hand for "whatever will make it work" it's a lazy way of doing `B.reshape(n, len(B)//n)`.

Based on your question it seems like the array B might just be homogenous array, (ie `all(B == j)`), in which case you could just do:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros(10)
j = 1.

C = np.zeros([10, 3])
C[:, 0] = A
C[:, 1:] = j
C = C.ravel()
```